# Arc length of locus of center of curvature

Tags: curvature

If $ S_1 $is the arc length of the locus of center of curvature of a curve, then show that

$$\dfrac{dS_1}{ds} =\dfrac{ \sqrt{(\kappa^2\tau^2 + \kappa^{'2})}}{\kappa^2} =\sqrt{ (\dfrac{\rho}{\sigma})^2+\rho^{'2}} $$

$\kappa$=  curvature ,$\,\rho = $  radius of curvature,$\tau$ = torsion, 
$\sigma=1/\tau = $ radius of torsion.

k' and rho ' I could not figure out what they represent . This is because question itself does not specify these symbols. 
Sorry for the inconvenience. You might guess why I this question is giving me tough time. But anyone who can guess these symbols and give anyway to approach this problem would do a huge favour on me.

My approach: My knowledge and resources to study this topic is limited. I know derivative of radius of curvature is derivative of arc length of locus of center of curvature. But can't move beyond this point. Could Somebody throw some light on way forward for this question.

Thanks.

Comment: In 3D differential geometry? Please define the symbols.

Comment: Yeah added those symbols which I knew. It's a 3d differential geometry only related to curvature torsion etc.

Comment: The derivative is with arc length. Please verify at first with a simple case 2D circle. Also is time to start with Latex/MathJax

Comment: The difference of arc length of "touched" evolute is the difference of radii of curvature.. basic property for involutes in 2D.

Comment: Yes true ! But what to do with this particular problem.

Comment: Please check if my latexing is ok.

Comment: Yeah precisely ! Thanks for this edit,